# Java Thread wait() => blocked?

Tags: java, concurrency

According to [Java thread state info](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) calling wait() will result a thread to go in BLOCKED state. However this piece of code will result (after being called) in a Thread in WAITING State.

```
class bThread extends Thread {
    public synchronized void run() {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Have I got something wrong? Can anybody explain this behaviour to me?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Side note: You should associate your wait call with a condition.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The thread is WAITING until it is notified. Then it becomes BLOCKED trying to reenter the synchronized region until all other threads have left.

Relevant parts from the link you posted (about WAITING):

> For example, a thread that has called Object.wait() on an object is waiting for another thread to call Object.notify() or Object.notifyAll() on that object.

and (about BLOCKED):

> A thread in the blocked state is waiting for a monitor lock to [...] reenter a synchronized block/method after calling Object.wait.

The last part occurs when the thread tries to return from wait(), but not until then.

Comment: is that means a blocked thread is in a loop to gain the lock? aka a thread in blocked state cost cpu time?

Comment: @user2807219: No, typically not. The thread would be in the ready queue of a mutex protecting the synchronised region, in the same way as if you were calling a synchronised function that is locked by another thread. The main cost to worry about with lock contention is typically that it forces context switches on the program (i.e. storing and restoring the state of the running thread in the CPU), which are relatively costly.

Answer (score 14):

The monitor executes one thread at a time. Assuming you have T1-T10 threads, 9 are `BLOCKED` and one is `RUNNABLE`. Every once in a while, the monitor picks a new thread to run. When that happens, the chosen/current thread, say T1, goes from `RUNNABLE` to `BLOCKED`. Then another thread, say, T2, goes from `BLOCKED` to `RUNNABLE`, becoming the current thread.

When one of the threads needs some information to be made available by another thread, you use `wait()`. In that case, the thread will be flagged as `WAITING` until it is `notify()`ed. So, a thread that is waiting will not be executed by the monitor until then. An example would be, wait until there are boxes to be unloaded. The guy loading boxes will notify me when that happens.

In other words, both `BLOCKED` and `WAITING` are status of inactive threads, but a `WAITING` thread cannot be `RUNNABLE` without going to `BLOCKED` first. `WAITING` threads "don't want" to become active, whereas `BLOCKED` threads "want" to, but can't, because it isn't their turn.

I think.

Comment: This answer explains best what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

Where did you see it say stuff like that?

In the same page you linked, [thread.state](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING), it clearly states that

WAITING will be after Object.wait()

BLOCKED will be before entering synchronized

Comment: Oh, I see what might have confused you. " BLOCKED=>   or reenter a synchronized block/method after calling Object.wait." .. notice the "reenter a synchronized block"

Answer (score 2):

Waiting is when it's not doing anything at all. Blocked is when it's trying to start running again but hasn't been allowed to yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is some confusing terminology going on here.
When a thread calls wait on an object it goes into the WAIT state.
When threads are *waiting* to grab a lock, they belong to the *wait* set for that lock, but they are in the BLOCKED state.

Confusing but somehow it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reminder, you should always call wait() inside a while loop waiting on the condition for entering the synchronized region/critical section. This is because Java has "spurious wakeups" (essentially, a thread can wakeup at any moment for no reason).

Comment: This should have been a comment. It has nothing to do with OP