# What circmustances can cause a thread to be transferred from the wait queue to the blocked queue?

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduling

Under what conditions can this happen?

As far as I know

Blocked queue is a buffer between threads producing objects and consuming objects.

Wait queue prevents threads from competing for the same lock.

So thread gets a lock, but is unable to be passed onto consumer as it is now busy?

Comment: Those two things are not related to each other. `BlockingQueues` contain objects, not threads. Threads read and write from/to the queue, they don't get "transferred" to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between WAIT and BLOCKED thread states](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680422/difference-between-wait-and-blocked-thread-states)

Comment: You should check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680422/difference-between-wait-and-blocked-thread-states

Comment: Sorry if it doesn't make much sense, but the title is directly out of my past exam and found it rather confusing. cheers for the links.

Comment: this is your exam?? Good Luck!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question makes only sense under the assumption that it actually means “What circumstances can cause a thread to **change** from the `wait` **state** to the `blocked` **state**?”

There might be a particular scheduler implementation maintaining these threads in a dedicated queue, having to move threads from one queue to another upon these state changes and influencing the mind set of whoever originally formulated the question, but such a question shouldn’t be loaded with assumed implementation details. As a side note, while a queue of `runnable` threads would make sense, I can’t imagine a real reason to put `blocked` or `waiting` threads into a (global) queue.

If this is the original intention of the question, it should not be confused with Java classes implementing queues and having similar sounding names.

- A thread is in the `blocked` state if it tries to enter a `synchronized` method or code fragment while another thread owns the object monitor. From there, the thread will turn to the `runnable` state if the owner releases the monitor and the blocked thread succeeds in acquiring the monitor
- A thread is in the `waiting` state if performs an explicit action that can only proceed, if another thread performs an associated action, i.e. if the thread calls `wait` on an object, it can only proceed when another thread calls `notify` on the same object. If the thread calls `LockSupport.park()`, another thread has to call `LockSupport.unpark()` with that thread as argument. When it calls `join` on another thread, that thread must end its execution to end the wait. The `waiting` state may also end due to *interruption* or *spuriuos wakeups*.
- As a special case, Java considers threads to be in the `timed_waiting` state, if they called the methods mentioned above with a timeout or when it executes `Thread.sleep`. This state only differs from the `waiting` state in that the state might also end due to elapsed time.

When a thread calls `wait` on an object, it must own the object’s monitor, i.e. be inside a `synchronized` method or code block. The monitor is released upon this call and reacquired when returning. When it can’t be reacquired immediately, the thread will go from the `waiting` or `timed_waiting` state to the `blocked` state.