# Java thread state transition, WAITING to BLOCKED, or RUNNABLE?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-state, java-threads

There seems to be a discrepancy between SO consensus and nearly every Java thread state diagram on the Internet; specifically, regarding thread state transition *from* `WAITING` after `notify()` or `notifyAll()` is invoked...

- *WAITING [never](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13664082/791406) goes directly to RUNNABLE*
- *The thread is WAITING until it is notified...Then it [becomes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2534158/791406) BLOCKED...*
- *Once this thread is notified, it [will not be runnable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15680579/791406)...This is..Blocked State.*

So the concensus on SO is: a thread transitions from `WAITING` to `BLOCKED` after invoking `notify()` or `notifyAll()`; diagram below illustrates this transition in green.

#### Question

Why do most [state diagrams on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20thread%20state%20diagram&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) illustrate the transition from `WAITING` to `RUNNABLE`, not `BLOCKED`? Depiction in red shows the incorrect transition; am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Why would I ask the person who drew the diagram when based on your comment they don't know better? :-)

Comment: I said "don't or didn't".  If you ask them, they may discover that they are wrong.  Or they may already have discovered.

Comment: So you're saying my diagram is more accurate than roughly 106,000 Google results? Hellulalua!

Comment: No.  I doubt that there are 106,000 different state diagram images on the web ...

Comment: If that is the case, what is special with `TIMED_WAIT` ? why it is directly going back to `RUNNABLE`, instead of moving to `BLOCKED` ?

Comment: there are some clearer answers, if you need. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15680422/2361308

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Any diagram that shows a `notify` invocation bringing a thread from WAITING to RUNNABLE is wrong (or is using an unclarified shortcut). Once a thread gets awoken from a `notify` (or even from a spurious wakeup) it needs to relock the monitor of the object on which it was waiting. This is the [`BLOCKED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED) state.

> Thread state for a thread blocked waiting for a monitor lock. A thread
>   in the blocked state is waiting for a monitor lock to enter a
>   synchronized block/method or reenter a synchronized block/method after
>   calling `Object.wait`.

This is explained in the javadoc of [`Object#notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--):

> The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current
>   thread relinquishes the lock on this object.

and [`Object#wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--)

> The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor
>   and resumes execution.

Comment: Makes sense. But, surely that's true of `TIMED_WAITING` too then?

Comment: Except if it has entered the `TIMED_WAITING` state due to `sleep(t)` that is.

Comment: @mystarrocks According to the [`Thread.State` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED), `WAITING` is for the parameterless `Object#wait`, while `TIMED_WAITING` is for the overload that accepts a wait time. Yes, this applies to both. Concerning `sleep`, a thread doesn't unlock any held monitors, it still owns them by the time it wakes up.

Answer (score 2):

A thread is in **WAITING** state goes in **BLOCK** state,until it acquires monitor by notify and become **RUNNABLE**.

Same applies for **TIMEDWAITING**,it goes in **BLOCK** state,if monitor is hold by some other thread,even though specified time has passed.*(your diagram need to be corrected)*

Answer (score 0):

I am focusing on the problem recently.

as the Oracle document [Thread.State](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) says we can use LockSupport.park() to put the current thread into 'WAITING' or 'TIMED_WAITING' state.

so when you try the [LockSupport.unpark()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html#unpark(java.lang.Thread)), the specified thread will return to 'RUNNABLE' from 'WAITING'/'TIMED_WAITING'. (I am not sure whether it will go through the 'BLOCKED' state)

Comment: I think LockSupport.unpark() will cause the specified thread state changing from WAITING to RUNNABLE directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth to mention that is also true for `Thread.interrupt()` method during `WAITING` state while in `lock.wait()` method.

`Thread.interrupt()` method will firstly make `WAITING` thread `BLOCKED` with `isInterrupted` flag set to true, and only after reacquiring lock interrupted thread will be able to throw `InterruptedException` (that is obvious, as it cannot handle exception, by that continuing execution without having exclusive lock before). ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698977/thread-interrupt-will-it-cancel-oncoming-wait-call/68421310#68421310))

Simply to say

Always `WAITING -> BLOCKED` to be able again compete for the lock, and after that to acquire it eventually and run its' code `RUNNABLE`.